# CorelDraw: is it possible to change outline thickness forever in all documents

Tags: corel-draw

I've got points as the outline thickness (OT) unit, I want it to always be millimeters.

But:

1. I tried setting default OT (which changes the unit,too) by unselecting everything and pressing F12. It works, but only in the current document.
2. I tried saving the document parameters as default via Tools - Save settings as default. This changes the OT unit to millimeters in all new documents, but old documents still have OT measured in points.

Is there a way to change points to millimeters everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on old documents to my knowledge. Only for new documents.

Comment: IT would be odd that a setting that may be set by document author would be overriden. BUt ist a abit of a design problem how do you accomodate overrides, and overrides to overrides.